# How to expand a data.frame containing a column with a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with one column containing a list of values:

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:2, parent=c("Jon", "Mark"))
d$children <-  list(c("Mary", "James"), c("Greta", "Sally"))
```

How to transform this data.frame to the following structure:

```
target_df <- data.frame(id=1:4, parent=c("Jon", "Jon","Mark", "Mark"), children = c("Mary", "James","Greta", "Sally"))
```

Comment: Do you intend that `id` is lost in the translation? Or would it make more sense for `id=rep(1:2,each=2)` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `unnest` from `tidyr` or you can map the `tidyverse`, sorry about earlier, I have mapped `tidyverse` .Rprofile file. Anyways

```
library(tidyverse) #or map library(tidyr) whatever suits you
d %>% 
  unnest(children) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:row_number()) #You may not want to run this if you want to keep your original id
```

Also in **base R** way:

```
d_new <- do.call('rbind', do.call('Map', c(data.frame, d)))
```

Again , to reset id, we have to use `1:nrow(d)`

```
d_new$id <- 1:nrow(d) #This may not be required if you don't want to reset your id
```

Thanks for all the comments , they are all welcomed, and Yes I am overwhelmed.
Thanks to @Ronak Shah, @r2evans

Comment: This is likely what the OP *needs*, but it does not produce the intended output currently listed in the question. There, `id=1:4`, and without clarification I suggest against `%>% mutate(id=row_number())` or similar kludge.

Comment: You could use pipe this into `mutate(id = row_number())` to correct the `id` feature

Comment: ... @DaveGruenewald, that's precisely what I suggested *against* doing (see my other comments), since it is losing information.

Comment: @r2evans Ah, you had edited yours while I submitted mine.  Agreed, you obviously lose information, but ultimately depends on OP's needs.